# PHP use an external variable in an extending class

Tags: php, class, variables, tcpdf, extend

I'm using TCPDF to make an award generator.
It checks the type of award and based on that it fills in the image_path variable (and some other variables that had nothing to do with this question.

```
switch($award){
    case 25:
        $img_file = '../../img/award_25.png';
        break;
    case 50:
        $img_file = '../../img/award_50.png';
        break;
    ... and so on ...
}
```

A little further, as seen in example_051 of TCPDF they extend the class to define the background image.
The path to that image is the one that is in the variable $img_file created above.

```
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Header() {
        // get the current page break margin
        $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
        // get current auto-page-break mode
        $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
        // disable auto-page-break
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
        // margins Left, Top, Right, Bottom in pixels
        $this->Image($img_file, -9, -8, 316, 225, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
        // restore auto-page-break status
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
        // set the starting point for the page content
        $this->setPageMark();
    }
}
```

Due to the scope the variable $image_file is not known within the extend. Is there a way I could make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `$GLOBALS` variables 
here is a example

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    $GLOBALS['b'] = $GLOBALS['a'] + $GLOBALS['b'];
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

More on Variables scopes [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: After replacing $img_file by $GLOBALS['img_file'] in the extension of this class the variable is still empty
i.e. die($GLOBALS['img_file']); at the end of the extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
protected $img_file;
 public function __construct($img_file)
    {
        $this->img_file = $img_file;
    }
    public function Header() {
        // get the current page break margin
        $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
        // get current auto-page-break mode
        $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
        // disable auto-page-break
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
        // margins Left, Top, Right, Bottom in pixels
        $this->Image($img_file, -9, -8, 316, 225, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
        // restore auto-page-break status
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
        // set the starting point for the page content
        $this->setPageMark();
    }
}
$MYPDF = new MYPDF($img_file);
```

Comment: Somehow this results in a TCPDF ERROR: Empty font family

http://pastebin.com/8DekH7KL

Comment: You might need to call the parent constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make variable $img_file a global for use inside the function.
This needs to be done inside the function
Manual here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

```
public function Header() {
    global $img_file;
    // get the current page break margin
    $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
  private $data = array();

  public function setData($key, $value) {
    $this->data[$key] = $value;
  }

  public function Header() {
    $this->data['invoice_no'];
    .... 
  }
}    
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); 
$pdf->setData('invoice_no', $invoice_no);
```